# How do you change the level translation for log4j SyslogAppender?

Tags: java, log4j, syslog

By default, the FATAL level in log4j will map to emergency in Syslog.  Because of IT syslog usage requirements in our corporation, I need FATAL to map to syslog alert instead.

Does anyone know of a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is guidance [here](http://kazed.blogspot.com/2009/12/using-syslog-appender-in-log4j.html) on how to do this by overriding the `append` method in the SyslogAppender class.  afai can see the mappings in `log4j` are hard-coded.

> If you use logger.fatal(), the
>   standard log4j syslog appender will
>   log this message with the highest
>   syslog severity, which is level 0,
>   "emerg". This level is usually
>   reserved for the most urgent operating
>   system related messages and on most
>   Unix systems will print the message on
>   the terminal session of every logged
>   in user. For most applications, this
>   is probably not what you want. If an
>   application encounters a fatal error,
>   it should log the message as a lower
>   level like "critical", level 2. You
>   can do this by implementing an
>   appender which overrides the "append"
>   method.